# Inicio sesion pero no muestra la siguiente vista

Tags: android

tengo un problema inicio sesion correctamente en LoginActivity no muestra la siguiente vista que es MainActivity.

> LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Creo los elementos
EditText etMatricula, etPass;
public Button btnIngresar;
public TextView txtView;
JSONArray ja;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Inicializo los elementos
    etMatricula = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_matricula);
    etPass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    btnIngresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ingresar);
    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_registrar);

    btnIngresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //pongo (ip/carpeta_proyecto/archivo) y veo que el usuario sea el que esta en el EditText matricula
            ConsultaPass("http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/ride_app/consulta.php?user="+etMatricula.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    txtView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent ride = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegistroActivity.class);
            startActivity(ride);
        }
    });

}//onCreate

private void ConsultaPass(String URL) {

    Log.i("url",""+URL);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest =  new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                //en el JA guarda la espuesta que le manda el WEB SERVICE
                ja = new JSONArray(response);
                //pone en contra la contraseña que se encuentra en el JA
                String contra = ja.getString(2);
                //si contra es igual a lo que se encuentra en el EditText pasa
                if(contra.equals(etPass.getText().toString())){
                    //muestro un toast de bienvenido
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bienvenido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //creo el intent
                    Intent main = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    //lanzo el intent
                    startActivity(main);

                }else{ //de lo contrario
                    //muestro mensaje de error
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"verifique su contraseña", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //si el servidor no devuelve nada mostrar mensaje de error
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El usuario no existe en la base de datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);



}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que retornas un json?

Comment: obtengo un Json  ahi dice en el codigo, pero no es ese el problema porque cuando testeo la app me muestra el toast de Bienvenido, entonces si esta entrando correctamente pero lo esta mostrando la vista

Comment: @Javierfr que se obtiene en response aquí????  ja = new JSONArray(response);

Comment: Es importante que agregues el valor de response para determinar el problema.

Comment: El response es la respuesta del web sevice y lo pongo en un JSON

Comment: Esta entrando correctamente el la imagen se muestra que me esta dando el toast de Bienvenido pero no esta lanzando la siguiente Vista

Comment: Quieren que agregue el codigo de la siguiente Vista?

Comment: Porque no revisas el LogCat? Agrega tu AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
  JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(response);
  if(result.length()==0){
    Toast.makeText(access.this,"Acceso Incorrecto",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Limpiar();
  }else{
    JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(0);
    String id = jo.getString("clave");
    String rol = jo.getString("rol");
    switch (rol){
      case "Root":
      Toast.makeText(access.this,"Correcto",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Limpiar();
      break;

      default:
        Toast.makeText(access.this,"Acceso Incorrecto",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Limpiar();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Esque lo que pasa en mi codigo es si esta entrando correctamente porque me da el mensaje de Bienvenida pero no esta mostrando la vista

Comment: mmm esta raro, si la declaraste bien...

Comment: Si ya se pero ni idea porque no me este mostrando la vista

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada todas las actividades deben ser declaradas en el manifest.
En este caso `LoginActivity`debe ser la actividad que se lanza primero (LAUNCHER):

```
<application ....      
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Al código para iniciar una nueva actividad hay que agregar `finish();`para
que la `LoginActivity` se destruya e inicie la `MainActivity`. Pero además, revisando la documentación de Android [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) se debe agregar ciertas flags:

```
Intent main = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
main.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); 
startActivity(main);
finish();
```

El `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` destruye todo el task asociada a la actividad o sea todo lo que esta en el stack (pila)
de esa actividad, por lo tanto no será posible regresar a la LoginActivity al pulsar el botón regresar. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`esta activity, en este caso MainActivity, será el inicio de un nuevo task en el stack.

Comment: @armen para evitar confusión y que no parezca que estás haciendo una pregunta, te recomendaría intentar explicar por qué debería agregar el método y cómo solucionaría el problema... Incuso agregar el código final completo seguramente le sume calidad a tu respuesta. Pensemos que no es sólo al autor de la pregunta a quien estás respondiendo, sino a cualquier futuro lector. La idea del sitio es aportar preguntas y respuestas con la mayor calidad posible. Más info en [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que debes guardar la referencia de tu `Activity` en una variable global. Estás utilizando el contexto que maneja la subclase.

Suponiendo que tienes tu `Activity` en una variable `activity`:

```
activity.startActivity(main);
finish();
```

Ó intenta:

```
LoginActivity.this.startActivity(main);
finish();
```

Déjame saber si te funciona, pienso que ahi está el error.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo un login muy parecido al tuyo en mi app, la única diferencia es que al crear el Intent lo hago con getApplicationContext. Prueba a ver si puede ser tu solución.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Slide_Menu_Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Acuerdate siempre de usar finish() para que el usuario no vuelva al login por error y destruir la actividad y así liberar memoria.